# Spring Boot 2.3+ no longer prints useful errors information for validation (from MethodArgumentNotValidException)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a user request payload

```
class UserRequest {
  @NotBlank
  String firstName;
  @NotBlank
  String lastName;

  @Min(18)
  @Max(65)
  Integer age;
  ..
}
```

Starting with 2.3+, I have enabled below to show error message:

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

Which works fine but it no longer shows errors that I used to see if there was a validation error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-08T20:27:18.834+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Validation failed for object='userRequest'. Error count: 2",
  "path": "/user"
}
```

Above isn't very descriptive to the end user what failed the validation, as opposed to previous versions with a `errors` field:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-08T20:27:18.834+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [..],
      "arguments": [..],
      "defaultMessage": "must be greater than or equal to 18
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
  "message": "Validation failed for object='userRequest'. Error count: 2",
  "path": "/user"
}
```

Is there any easy way to enable back old behavior or do I have to provide custom exception handling through some ControllerAdvice?